# Generalized step function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

What are the properties of functions of the form $ \sum\limits_{s_n<x} {c_n}$ where $\sum{c_n}$ converges absolutely and $s_n$ is a sequence in $[0,1]$. In particular, are there very nice sufficient conditions to tell if a given function can be expressed in this form?

Comment: What kind of conditions are you looking for? For instance they are the $BV$ functions whose derivative is the measure $\mu=\sum_{n} c_n \delta_{s_n}$, but this is almost a tautology

Comment: I think there are many easy to prove necessary conditions, but I don't know any nice sufficient conditions on them, also I thought maybe this is a well known class of functions, and someone can point me to some literature